# CloudFormation StackSet S3 Error: the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'ap-southeast-1'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to deploy my lambda functions using CloudFormation StackSets to multiple AWS accounts and regions. But failed because of the below error

> ResourceLogicalId:OfficeHoursAutoScalingStart, ResourceType:AWS::Lambda::Function, ResourceStatusReason:Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: AuthorizationHeaderMalformed. S3 Error Message: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'ap-southeast-1'

It seems like its a permissions thing? How do I resolve this?

My template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Description: 'Skynet. AWS Management Assistant'
Parameters:
  AppName:
    Type: String
    Description: Prefix for resources
    Default: skynet-lambda-stackset
  ArtifactsBucket:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 bucket storing lambda function zip
  ArtifactZipPath:
    Type: String
    Description: Path to lambda function zip
  CostCenter:
    Type: String
    Description: Cost center
    Default: Admin
  Owner:
    Type: String
    Description: Owner
    Default: Jiew Meng

Resources:
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub '${AppName}-lambda'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - lambda.amazonaws.com
              - apigateway.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess'
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaFullAccess'
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess'
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess'
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess'

  NewEc2AutoTag:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
        S3Key: !Ref ArtifactZipPath
      Handler: ec2/newEc2_autoTag.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      FunctionName: 'NewEC2_AutoTag'
      Description: 'Auto tag new EC2 instances with Owner tag'
      Timeout: 30
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Tags:
        - Key: Cost Center
          Value: !Ref CostCenter
        - Key: Owner
          Value: !Ref Owner

  NewEc2Event:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AppName}-newEc2
      Description: On new EC2 instance created
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - 'aws.ec2'
        detail-type:
          - 'AWS API Call via CloudTrail'
        detail:
          eventName:
            - RunInstances
      Targets:
        - !Ref NewEc2AutoTag

  AfterhoursEc2Shutdown:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
        S3Key: !Ref ArtifactZipPath
      Handler: ec2/afterHours_shutdown.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      FunctionName: 'Afterhours_Shutdown'
      Description: 'Shutdown instances tagged Auto Shutdown: true'
      Timeout: 30
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Tags:
        - Key: Cost Center
          Value: !Ref CostCenter
        - Key: Owner
          Value: !Ref Owner

  AfterHoursEvent:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AppName}-afterHours
      Description: Triggered on weekdays 2400 SGT
      ScheduleExpression: cron(0 16 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THUR,FRI *)
      Targets:
        - !Ref AfterhoursEc2Shutdown
        - !Ref AfterhoursAutoScalingShutdown

  OfficeHoursEc2Start:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
        S3Key: !Ref ArtifactZipPath
      Handler: ec2/officeHours_start.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      FunctionName: 'OfficeHours_Start'
      Description: 'Starts instances with Auto Shutdown: true'
      Timeout: 30
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Tags:
        - Key: Cost Center
          Value: !Ref CostCenter
        - Key: Owner
          Value: !Ref Owner

  OfficeHoursEvent:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AppName}-officeHours
      Description: Triggered on 7AM SGT weekdays
      ScheduleExpression: cron(0 23 ? * SUN,MON,TUE,WED,THU *)
      Targets:
        - !Ref OfficeHoursEc2Start
        - !Ref OfficeHoursAutoScalingStart

  StartedEc2ConfigureDns:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
        S3Key: !Ref ArtifactZipPath
      Handler: ec2/started_configureDns.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      FunctionName: 'StartedEc2_ConfigureDns'
      Description: 'When EC2 started, configure DNS if required'
      Timeout: 30
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Tags:
        - Key: Cost Center
          Value: !Ref CostCenter
        - Key: Owner
          Value: !Ref Owner

  Ec2StartedEvent:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AppName}-ec2-started
      Description: Triggered on EC2 starts
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - 'aws.ec2'
        detail-type:
          - 'EC2 Instance State-change Notification'
        detail:
          state:
            - running
      Targets:
        - !Ref StartedEc2ConfigureDns

  AfterhoursAutoScalingShutdown:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
        S3Key: !Ref ArtifactZipPath
      Handler: autoscaling/afterHours_shutdown.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      FunctionName: 'Afterhours_AutoScalingShutdown'
      Description: 'Scales down autoscaling groups tagged Auto Shutdown: true'
      Timeout: 30
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Tags:
        - Key: Cost Center
          Value: !Ref CostCenter
        - Key: Owner
          Value: !Ref Owner

  OfficeHoursAutoScalingStart:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
        S3Key: !Ref ArtifactZipPath
      Handler: autoscaling/officeHours_start.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      FunctionName: 'OfficeHours_AutoScalingStart'
      Description: 'Scales up auto scaling groups that are scaled down to 0 and tagged autostart: true'
      Timeout: 30
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Tags:
        - Key: Cost Center
          Value: !Ref CostCenter
        - Key: Owner
          Value: !Ref Owner

  NewAutoScalingGroupEvent:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AppName}-autoscaling-new
      Description: Triggered when new autoscaling group created
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - 'aws.autoscaling'
        detail-type:
          - 'AWS API Call via CloudTrail'
        detail:
          eventName:
            - CreateAutoScalingGroup
      Targets:
        - !Ref NewAutoScalingGroupAutoTag

  NewAutoScalingGroupAutoTag:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
        S3Key: !Ref ArtifactZipPath
      Handler: autoscaling/new_autoTag.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      FunctionName: 'NewAutoScalingGroup_AutoTag'
      Description: 'Tags new autoscaling groups with owner and autoshutdown tags if not existing'
      Timeout: 30
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Tags:
        - Key: Cost Center
          Value: !Ref CostCenter
        - Key: Owner
          Value: !Ref Owner
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you have created the s3 bucket (referenced by variable `ArtifactsBucket` in your template) in AWS region `ap-southeast-1`.

Using AWS Stacksets, You have selected `us-east-1` as one of the regions in ***Deployment Order***.

The AWS Stackset passes the **SAME parameters** to all the stacks which it tries to create in multiple regions/accounts.

So when it is trying to create the lambda function `OfficeHoursAutoScalingStart` in `us-east-1` region, It is tryin to access the s3 bucket(GETObject request) in `us-east-1` region itself, with the same bucket name.

ie. It is presuming that the s3 bucket with name passed by `ArtifactsBucket`parameter, is present in us-east-1 itself.But since the source code of the lambda function is actually in the bucket present in region `ap-southeast-1`,the `header malformed error` is thrown. In this case the bucket name is matching, but the region is not.

Currently, when you create lambda function using CloudFormation, *there is a restriction that the S3 bucket that contains the source code of your Lambda function must be in the SAME region as the STACK which you are creating*. [Doc Reference Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html)

If this is the issue, then as a fix, you can think of creating s3 buckets (add region-name as a prefix to the bucket name) in the required regions and use them in the template based on the region.

```
Example:
us-east-1-lambdabkt
us-east-2-lambdabkt
ap-southeast-1-lambdabkt
```

Comment: I solved the error with your suggestions already. But now I encounter another permissions error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751355/aws-cloudformation-stackset-s3-accessdenied maybe you can help too :)