# Can AWS Lambda access S3 buckets from other regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I currently try to use AWS Lambda. The lambda function should load the zip file (> 10 MB) from an S3 Bucket. The S3 bucket is located in `eu-central-1` while the lambda function is in `lambda:us-east-1`.

When I try to save the lambda function, I get:

> Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: AuthorizationHeaderMalformed. S3 Error Message: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-central-1'

Is that really the problem? Is it possible to move the lambda function?

The IAM role which executes the Lambda function has the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy.

Comment: AWS lambda is available in eu-central-1: https://aws.amazon.com/de/about-aws/whats-new/2016/03/aws-lambda-available-in-eu-frankfurt/

Comment: do you give the right s3 authorizations for the user that you use in lambda?

Comment: @Edwin Hm. Maybe not. How do I do that?

Comment: @Edwin you shouldn't use an AWS "user" in Lambda, you should assign an IAM role to the function. That role should be the entity you assign the appropriate S3 permissions to.

Comment: @MarkB by user I meant IAM (just had an lapsus), Martin check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-how-setup.html#replication-iam-role-intro and this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html

Comment: I've added the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy to the executing IAM role. Still the same error.

Comment: Answered perfectly here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745297/cloudformation-stackset-s3-error-the-region-us-east-1-is-wrong-expecting-ap?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lambda function has  to be in the same region as the S3 bucket you specify at "S3 link URL*":

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation verifying this. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: We need a feature request to get rid of this. It makes using Lambda with CLoudFormation/SAM pretty useless.

Answer (score 7):

You can access an S3 bucket in a different region from Lambda. If you are using Python boto3 library, the following code will help you:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-central-1')
```

In fact you can access any resource in a different region from AWS Lambda.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I can't even save the function. I get this error when I try to save it within the GUI.

Comment: And I just added it everywhere. Still have the same issue.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR your answer is right -- but for a different question.  *"lambda function should load the zip file"* in the question is not a clear and accurate statement of the problem. 
 OP is trying to load or store the Lambda function **code** in the bucket, cross-region... not *"access S3 buckets from other regions"* (from a running Lambda function).

Comment: For reasons already mentioned. This is an Infrastructure question not an AWS SDK question. .