# How to specify S3 bucket region in CloudFormation template for lambda .zip code

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have one `S3 bucket` in `us-west-2` with my `.zip file` containing the code for `lambda` inside it.

I would like to use this same bucket when Im deploying my lambda using `CloudFormation template` in other regions as well.
I thought that since S3 is a global service it should be possible.
But it gives an error for lambda creation from another region.

Is there a way to do this?
I found only these values to be allowed in Code section of the template.

```
"Code": {
          "S3Bucket": "my-new-bucket",
          "S3Key": "my_lambda.zip"
        },
```

Comment: unfortunately no the lambda and the s3 bucket has to be in the same region please check the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48344630/2544875

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can AWS Lambda access S3 buckets from other regions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343873/can-aws-lambda-access-s3-buckets-from-other-regions)

Comment: AWS Lambda is a regional service. It requires the code in Amazon S3 to be in the same region as the AWS Lambda function.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Yeah i had to figure out some other way as this cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use different region as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-function.html):

> An Amazon S3 bucket in the **same Amazon Web Services Region** as your function. The bucket can be in a different Amazon Web Services account.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, you have to have the code in an S3 bucket in the same region as the Lambda. While the S3 service is global, the buckets are not.

There are some options to do what you want to do.

1. [S3 object replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html) can be used to replicate the objects from one bucket to another. This does have a limit on just one additional region.
2. Use [CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/). CodePipeline will automatically replicate the artifacts to the appropriate region for you. You still have to have a bucket in each region you are deploying to, but you don't have to worry about copying the artifacts. [Add a cross-Region action in CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-cross-region.html) shows an example of how this is setup.

Comment: yes its clear now since you mentioned that "S3 is global but buckets are not".